# Adding columns resulting from GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got stuck in a scenario where I need to add columns from two rows after using GROUP BY.
My query goes as:

```
select AcctId,DC,sum(TrnAmt) from TableId
group by AcctId,DC
order by AcctId,DC
```

Result:-

```
VcrAcctId      DrCr  SumTranAmt
51            C    37469
51      D      37000
```

My expected result is:

```
VcrAcctId      Actual
51     37469-37000
```

How can I get my expected result in the same query?

Comment: Are there always exactly two rows per `VcrAcctId`? If not what should be shown?

Comment: NO, there can be only one VcrAcctId, in that case DrCr column will be either D or C with one SumTranAmt

Comment: So you actually always want to show `C-D` if there are two rows and what if there is just one? Is it differentiated in the result if it is a `C` or a `D`? Are you in fact trying to get the net value of all credits and debits so that ideally you would want the result `469` as the result for your example data?

Comment: exactly, i have a transaction table in which an account can have multiple Credits or Debits or only single credit or debit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments I think you need

```
SELECT AcctId,
       Sum(CASE DC
             WHEN 'C' THEN TrnAmt
             WHEN 'D' THEN -TrnAmt
             ELSE 0
           END) AS DC
FROM   TableId
GROUP  BY AcctId
ORDER  BY AcctId
```

If in fact you do want the credits and debits split out you can use

```
SELECT AcctId,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN DC = 'C' THEN TrnAmt
             ELSE 0
           END) AS C,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN DC = 'D' THEN TrnAmt
             ELSE 0
           END) AS D
FROM   TableId
GROUP  BY AcctId
ORDER  BY AcctId
```

You could cast the `SUM` expressions to `varchar` and concatenate them to get the results shown in the question if that is what is actually needed.

Comment: hi Martin..can you give a solution to my link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899909/calculating-from-rows-and-columns..

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming Actual is ordered on DrCR, so that C result row comes before D result row.
Also, replace Table1 with a CTE from your original query, so that you first sum up per VcrAcctId and DC.

```
SELECT VcrAcctId, STUFF((SELECT '-' + convert(varchar(100),SumTranAmt)
              FROM Table1 I
              WHERE Table1.VcrAcctId = I.VcrAcctID 
              ORDER BY DrCr
             FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
FROM Table1
Group by VcrAcctId
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65276/3)

Comment: my query is Resulting from a CTE query, I don't know whether consecutive CTE querry works or not.

Comment: Performance will be worse though, the `XML PATH` subquery referencing the CTE will likely cause multiple evaluations of the underlying `group by` query that defines the CTE.